# CSS table reshape to 2-columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table in html, containing this structured data:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>label1</td><td>value1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>label2</td><td>value2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>label3</td><td>value3</td></tr>
  ...
</table>
```

This is a long list. I would like to be able to but each n+1-th row next to the n th row, like this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>label1</td><td>value1</td></tr><tr><td>label2</td><td>value2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>label3</td><td>value3</td></tr><tr><td>label4</td><td>value4</td></tr>
  ...
</table>
```

So the structure stays the same, but the CSS layout would take care of putting each second row on the right, so the users sees 2 columns of (field, value) in one row.

Any hints?

UPDATE:

This trick will do it, but destroys the table-layout, so not usable.

```
TABLE TR
{
    float:left;
}
TABLE TR:nth-child(2n+1)
{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that can be done in CSS (or anything else). A ROW by definition is a ROW (i.e. a new line). I may be wrong but I don't think so.

Comment: You're better of writing some code to reformat the HTML and letting tables behave naturally.

Comment: One solution would be to put two tables next to each other...

Your solution at the bottom of the post works fine for me though, you say it destroys the table layout but thats exactly what I was going to suggest doing and it works fine for me in jsfiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/entVE/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out and let know is that you want?

### Your Html

```
<table>
  <tr><td>label1</td><td>value1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>label2</td><td>value2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>label3</td><td>value3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>label4</td><td>value4</td></tr>
  <!-- more stuff here -->
</table>
```

### CSS:

```
tr {
  float: left;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: left;
  padding-right: 10px; /* You can edit this line and add as per your style */
}
```

Works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox. Not checked in IE

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/mMnLT/3/)

Comment: This breaks the table layout (cells will differ in size) as you will see when you enter other values than the ones above. See my update that contains a similar approach

Comment: @RobAu How much width do you want to give for each td's? You should give the width for td in this case.